# Keyboard equivalent for UIButton

Tags: xcode7

Xcode newbie:  I'm trying to create a keyboard equivalent (return key) for a UIButton. I've created an outlet for the button, and I've noted the following code from these pages --  [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]; But where do I put this piece of code?  If someone out there has the patience to walk me through it, I'd be thankful.

Pat Cook